# How to Select Cell Based from Macro

Tags: vba, excel

This should be simple, not sure why I am having trouble with this.....
In a data input range that a user is entering data there is a "left" and a "right" side of the form. Not all the data in any given row has to be filled in. I want to create a macro (and assign it to a hot key I.E. ctrl-z  ) such that if it is hit it will position the active cell to be in the current row and in column "X". in other words hitting the ctrl-Z will cause the cursor to jump to column "X"

Answer (score 1):

In this case column "x" is actually column E:

```
Sub ToColE()
    Const colE = 5
    Dim offset As Integer
    offset = colE - ActiveCell.Column
    ActiveCell.offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=offset).Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Either of the following statements should do the trick.  Assign the macro shortcut from the Tools Menu --> Macros.

```
Public Sub SelectStuff()
    Cells(3, 5).Select
    Rows(17).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub MoveLeftOnForm()
    Dim rn As Integer
    rn = ActiveCell.Row
    Range("B" & rn).Select
End Sub
```

it assumes B is your leftmost column in the form.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it for you:

```
Public Sub SetUpKeyboardShortcut()
    Application.OnKey "^z", "SelectColInSelectedRow"
End Sub

Public Sub SelectColInSelectedRow()
    Const ColToSelect = "X"
    Range(ColToSelect & CStr(Selection.Row)).Select
End Sub
```

Just call SetUpKeyboardShortcut in the Workbook_Open event in the ThisWorkbook module.  I believe the code above needs to be stored in a standard module.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Public Sub go()
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Activate
End Sub
```

Just substitute the "5" with whatever column number you wish.  You should be able to assign a ctrl+z hotkey from the options on the macro menu.